# How get the min value of hash and print his key

Tags: ruby

I got

```
hash = {
  "Bitcoin" => "$6558.07",
  "Ethereum" => "$468.95",
  "XRP" => "$0.487526",
  "Sprouts" => "$4.5e-07"
}
```

for get the max I do:

```
hash.max_by{ |k, v| v[1..v.length-1].to_f}
#=> ["Bitcoin", "$6558.07"]
```

but if I do the same for min like :

```
hash.min_by{ |k, v| v[1..v.length-1].to_f}
#=> ["Sprouts", "$4.5e-07"]
```

so I tried `hash.min` but I don't found how puts the good key.

Comment: How much is `"4.5e-07"` to float?

Comment: From min to max `[4.5e-07, 0.487526, 468.95, 6558.07]`, what's your expected output?, why?

Comment: `4.5e-07` is the [E-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation) for `0.00000045`. It's returned by `min_by` because it is the smallest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your only problem that you can't get the key name?

For example,  are you saying when you do:

```
puts hash.min_by{ |k, v| v[1..v.length-1].to_f}
```

you get

> Sprouts
>
> $4.5e-07

but you just want `Sprouts`?
If so you are just missing `.first`

```
key_of_min = hash.min_by{ |k, v| v[1..v.length-1].to_f}.first
```

or on a `puts` line

```
puts hash.min_by{ |k, v| v[1..v.length-1].to_f}.first
```

will give you just

> Sprouts